# Loading an whole Python project when hosting IronPython in C#

Tags: c#, ironpython

I've seen that there is documentation about how to execute or compile a Python script in C# by reading about Hosting approach for IronPython inside a .Net project: http://www.voidspace.org.uk/ironpython/dlr_hosting.shtml

But nothing is explaining clearly how to load an whole Python/IronPython project that contains several folders and files with a lot of import.

Is this something possible, or this approach is not appropriate for large project, and more for short scripts?

Comment: It's possible and it's appropriate for large projects. You just have to specify more concrete details. How do you run the project with the standard Python interpreter? what do you wish to achieve? etc.

Comment: Thing is I'm not a Python coder, so the first step for me is to find a tutorial that proves me that a huge Library, let's say [Python Audio Tools](https://github.com/tuffy/python-audio-tools), can be hosted in a C# project.

Comment: Python Audio Tools cannot be used in IronPython since it's a CPython extension library implemented in C. You can only use libraries written in pure Python. IronPython still doesn't know how to load C extension libraries written for CPython. There was a project [ironclad](https://code.google.com/p/ironclad/) that aimed to allow IronPython users to transparently import and use any compiled CPython extensions. But it seems that the project is dead. Although you can load any library written in C# into IronPython and use all it's functionality.

Comment: Good to read about this disambiguation between Python/CPython. And about my main concern, do you know if the procedure to follow between loading a single script and loading an whole project is very different when hosting IronPython in C#. When reading the different tutorial, what worries me is that examples are really basic: nothing is using more than one file or on-the-fly execution.

Comment: I guess I should just append everything in one single file? Sorry to sound like a guy who didn't tried a lot of thing. The truth is I spent days and night porting code from different language and I'm now afraid to start again in another a useless quest. Since porting using existing tools to port codes was a very bad initiative. So the idea of having a DLL that is able to digest (almost) any Pytoon code is seducing me, in term of portability.

Comment: You'll need a single "entrypoint" script to get everything started but it can import other Python modules as needed.

Comment: Ok, that sounds promising then!

Comment: @JeffHardy Just out of curiosity, is there currently an example or a tutorial about this situation, where there are more than one file?

Comment: Not that I know of, but the only real trick is using `engine.SetSearchPaths` to set up `sys.path` correctly and then just import as normal.